# When using set state hooks in a text input field, React thinks I'm changing the value to undefined

Tags: reactjs, debugging, react-hooks, react-router, controlled-component

So I'm running a pretty standard input form in one of my components called Start which feeds to App where it asks for the player's name. This uses React hooks to initialize a state, then changes the state `onChange`.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'

export default function Start() {
    const [playerName, setName] = useState("Player")
    function handleName (event){
        setName(event.value)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Player Name:</h3>
            <input type ="text" value={playerName} onChange={handleName}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

For some strange reason, whenever I type into the player name field, React thinks I am setting it to undefined, and gives me this error:

> Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen.

I further verified this through checking React Dev Tools. For some reason it thinks the new value is undefined every time I type anything in the box, but it still displays the correct lettering which is set to {playerName}!. This is within a Route/Switch as well if that makes any difference.

Any ideas what the issue/fix is?

Comment: I think the input value is inside `event.target.value`, while you're setting `setName(event.value)`, which is undefined ?

Comment: Yup, this was it. Shame on me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This means you are setting the input value to `undefined` because the `value` key is available on `event.target` and is undefined on `event`. hence the error

> This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen.